# How well does wisdom predict major life outcomes?

Tags: social-psychology

Wisdom has appeared to me to be a certain “persona non grata” in the field of psychology due to its enigmatic nature and unreliability in being measured, however what is the extent to which wisdom serves as a reliable predictor to major life outcomes such as life satisfaction and wealth? It appears merely from observation that one of the hallmarks signs of life success is the propensity and inclination of an individual towards amassing and processing experiential data, a quality more commonly known as knowledge—as such, successful people tend to be inclined towards knowledge. Wisdom (love for knowledge) can be expressed in terms of the big five personality framework: the wise tends to be open to experience, a fundamental pre-requisite on the subject of wisdom. Wisdom also tends to be correlated with conscientiousness as being methodical ensures the experiential data that is being processed is relevant and conducive to the systematic framework in which the individual operates—conscientious also happens to be a reliable predictor of success. The propensity to extraversion is uncorrelated with wisdom: if anything wise people tend to be introverted as this is beneficial in processing and recounting of experiential data. As the wise tends to being open, this consequently plays on levels of neuroticism: being too intellectually radical is a quality best described as “being on the edge”—thus a certain level of neuroticism is part and parcel of wisdom.

Below a study detailing the positive correlation between wisdom and the searching of life satisfaction.

https://www.researchgate.net/publication/322931327_Role_of_Wisdom_in_Searching_Life_Satisfaction_And_Happiness_among_Elderly_Men

Supporting evidence to my statements:
https://www.ijschooling.com/article_89433_1d6bbd68b8c1ae48bdde57346e47cbc6.pdf

Comment: Are you repeatedly making trivial edits to your post to 'bump' it and increase attention to your question?